# How to create a Brunch plugin?

Tags: node.js, brunch

I'd like to build a plugin for Brunch but I don't know where to start. The [Brunch plugin API documentation](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/plugins.md) is the closest I've found to a How-To guide but I don't know enough to make use of it. Ideally I'd like a detailed tutorial that walks me though from the beginning but I can't find anything on Google. Does anyone have tips for building a Brunch plugin?

Comment: Look at the source code of existing plugins, and use the API documentation you've already found for reference.

What do you want your plugin to do?

Comment: @es128: Thanks. I'll take a look at some source code. I'd like to write a plugin to compile handlebars templates to html at design time. That way the static html can be uploaded to the server with less JS dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in your question and the comments the Brunch plugin API documentation and source code of existing similar plugins are the best references for working on creating a new one.

For what you're trying to do [static-jade-brunch](https://github.com/ilkosta/static-jade-brunch) would be a good example to start off with.

Comment: In the time since I posted this answer a comprehensive Brunch guide has been published which includes a section on authoring plugins. https://github.com/brunch/brunch-guide/blob/master/content/en/chapter12-writing-a-plugin.md